# Fixing this 500 Error - Raspberry Pi /var/www to /home/pi/project/test.db

Tags: php, python, linux, sqlite

I'm just in the process of merging my project together and it's driving me nuts trying to figure this out.

Basically I have a python system written and it's residing in this directory:

```
/home/pi/project.
```

within that directory I have a sqlite3 db that I'm constantly updating and I'm trying to gain access to this from my dbConn.php file located in my `/var/www directory`.

However when given the absolute path

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/home/pi/Project/modules/test.db') or die("cannot open db");
```

I'm given 500 errors.

Is there anyway around this? or am I missing something stupid?

Comment: What server are you using? Do you have access to its log files?

Comment: It's Raspbian OS on the raspberry Pi

Comment: Can you try to wrap creating PDO object statement with `try {} catch(Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); }` and check if there were any exeptions thrown?

Comment: Turns out I never read the error correctly, it's actually the angular.js script that is struggling to get the dbconn.php file. I'll try changing the permissions and see how that works!

Comment: Have you got any results?

Comment: Not yet, I'm just putting in try catches into my angularjs code now.

Comment: raspbian is basically linux, all the logs should go to /var/log folder. do a tailf /var/log/{the_log_file} if you need to read it real time

Comment: Cheers guys! I've just done a tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log and it's now giving me meaningful error messages so I'll hopefully be able to follow the breadcrumbs and find a solution now!